# Ruby & Rails: Variable in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code and it is loaded in a helper-class

```
output += '<button class="del_account" param-del="{account.id}">delete</button>'
```

When I render this to html, account.id is just converted to a string. And not the 'id' that I need. How can I solve this? Because this isn't working either.

```
output += '<button class="del_account" param-del="#{account.id}">delete</button>'
```

or this

```
output += '<button class="del_account" param-del="' +account.id +'">delete</button>'
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Rails helper method `content_tag` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)) which makes things a bit cleaner and more readable.

```
output += content_tag(:button, "delete", :class => "del_account", :'param-del' => account.id)
```

Also, technically 'param-del' makes your HTML invalid - your custom attributes should begin with 'data-', so updating above would become:

```
output += content_tag(:button, "delete", :class => "del_account", :'data-account-id' => account.id)
```

Comment: Yes, I like this more than above. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use both `"` and `'` symbols then here is simple way to deal with them:

```
output += %[<button class="del_account" param-del="#{account.id}">delete</button>]
```

This way you can safely place any of mentioned symbols without worrying to escape them.